# Using JMS Selectors vs in-memory filtering

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-listener

I have a requirement to read messages from queue that gets filled in via Virtual Topic. Contemplating to have a JMS selector to read only the messages I require in the listener - but since I don't want the messages to be in the queue - I can either implement another listener which reads the remaining messages and just acknowledges it OR I can do it a single listener which doesn't have a JMS Selector but does this filtering in memory. 
Which approach is recommended?

Comment: Plus point for the JMS Selector is that it takes care of the scenarios where we do rollback. Only the valid messages which are selected via the JMS Selector are rolled back. In-memory filtering, we will have to do additional work in case of rollback.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the selectors. Filtering in memory sounds like reinventing the wheel and probably no as safe.